# How to achieve RSS based news roll?

Tags: javascript, rss

I want to make the titles of WordPress blog posts appear on a seperate homepage like they do at Apple.com next to "Hot News Headlines".

Here is the related source I found but I am unsure how to apply it to my own site:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss">
<script src="http://images.apple.com/home/scripts/ticker.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stealing Apple's code, you may want to use any number of freely-available widgets. [Google is your friend!](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en-us&q=rss+ticker+widget&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: I'm not trying to steal any code. Rather I want to learn how it's done and do it myself.